# Ubuntu installer hangs on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my notebook, but the installer hangs during the loading sequence.
Notebook is ASUS ROG GL552V (Core i7 4720HQ, 12 Gb RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M, an HDD and an SSD).
I'm using a USB pen drive for installation.
The installation freezes on this step.

[image]

There is already Windows 10 Home preinstalled on this PC.

I've tried:

- installing Ubuntu 17.04
- installing Kubuntu 16.04
- using different pen drives
- using pendrivelinux and Rufus tools to make a bootable pen drive
- booting these very pen drives on another PC with positive result (install actually loads and looks working fine)
- booting several times
- checking integrity of the flash drive by built-in utility has shown no errors

Secure Boot is disabled., CSM is enabled in the BIOS settings.

I tried everything that came to mind including resetting to BIOS defaults. I also tried a complete reformatting (slow one) of both USB drives with rewriting them. Then I found and read a lot of guides on seemingly common problems and the one that was the most interesting was [here](https://jeremymdyson.wordpress.com/2016/04/27/ubuntugnome-16-04-on-asus-rog-gl552v/).

Comment: Disable TPM at BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thanks for the answer. Didn't find such an option in my BIOS though. CSM is enabled, secure boot is disabled. Found an article about TPM (i didn't heard about this feature before) and I have run the "tpm.msc" utility. If understand it right there must be an option to turn TPM Off there, but i see nothing that looks like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, thanks to **DimanBG** from forum.ubuntu.ru managed to solve this problem. Practically I misunderstood some articles I read while looking for solution.

What i actually did after all and what helped me:

1. Disabled **Secure Boot** in BIOS
2. In GRUB 2 selected "Try UBUNTU..." and pressed "e".
3. In config that opened I deleted "quiet splash" and instead of it typed **"nouveau.modeset=0"** (without quotes).

I have an **Nvidia** GPU so I used "nouveau.modeset=0".

For people with other GPUs these parameters might help:

- for **Intel**: i915.modeset=0
- for **ATI**: radeon.modeset=0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Fix: Using the `nomodeset` command in the grub menu, plus removing second hdd.

For some reason the installation program didn't like the second harddrive and was getting confused. After successful installation, re-installed the second harddrive and all was good.