# Installer for ubuntu 16.04 64 bit not starting on Notebook HP - 15-ba085nl

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Notebook HP - 15-ba085nl but I'm facing a few issues:
- when I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 amd64 bit the installer freezes while starting (the issue is not related to the version the boot usb that I'm trying to use, I've checked and file  is correct. I also trying with Kubuntu 16.04 amd64bit but the installer doesn't start either
-I've successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 i386 (32 bit)  but GPU is not working: the screen often blinks and there are a lot of black rows appearing, I've tried to install the driver AMDGPU-PRO but installation fails due to the fact that i'm using i386 version.

Any Idea?  I probably can make the 32 bit work properly but how can I solve the issue with the 64 bit installer? Is there any way to try debug that?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the system is not able to use the AMD video card. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem thanks to this question [Ubuntu installer hangs on start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907027/ubuntu-installer-hangs-on-start?rq=1)

In order to start the installer correctly I clicked 'e' while on the grub page and edited the command by deleting "quiet splash" and adding "nomodeset".

Too bad that later on I doscovered there is no support yet for AMDGPU-PRO in Ubuntu 16.04.3
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

Comment: UPDATE: support for Ubuntu 16.04.3 is now available!